# why this android layout can not align in 6.0 but works below 6.0

Tags: layout, android-6.0-marshmallow

this is the xml layout.Anybody can tell me why?
There is one Linearlayout contains two relativelayout,and the relativelayout contains one textview.When I set the textview's textsize with 32sp and 24 sp,the questions is appear,they can't align in one baseline.

Comment: No code, no screenshot. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

There are two similar problems:
1.[Marshmallow RelativeLayout behaves strange with alignBaseline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32991273/marshmallow-relativelayout-behaves-strange-with-alignbaseline)
2.https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73697&thanks=73697

By the way, you'd better show the code.